# Inkscape For Dummies

Tags: inkscape

Iam using Inkscape for a project. I am making mugs and have converted photographs into patterns in order to fit them into shapes. How can I then convert them to a file type that can be opened in other programmes ie. Open Office or attach them in an email that is readable to people without Inscape?

Comment: I am a complete novice, hence the non correct use of computer terminology.

Answer (score 2):

Once you are done with your Inkscaping, you can go to <kbd>File</kbd> and click on <kbd>Export PNG Image</kbd>

This will let you export your current drawing into a PNG format, which is easily readable by any Image viewers or even the softwares that you have mentioned (Open Office or as email attachments).

Answer (score 2):

#### Vector graphics

Inkscape defaults output to [Scalable Vector Graphics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics) format (SVG) which is fully supported by most other applications including Open/Libre Office. It is also supported from another OS we may use. So there is not really any need for conversion.

[image]
<sup>Stop sign from Inkscape imported as SVG into Libre Office</sup>

As the name says a "scalable" vector graphic can be resized without loss in quality.

In the *File > Save As...* dialog there also is an option to export to other vector formats including [PDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format) which should be readable from any computer.

#### Bitmap

If however for any reason we need a bitmap graphic we can export it to [PNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics) through the *File > Export PNG Image* menu. File dimensions will have to be defined before exporting as scaling can not be done without loss later:

[image]

Comment: Inkscape's SVG is not fully compatible with CorelDraw (as far as I know). The gradient information gets lost. So, it is not correct to say that 'it is fully supported'.